# silverlight SaveFileDialog doesn't show up

Tags: silverlight, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a silverlight application where I use SaveFileDialog
It works fine on the dev/test machine
but when I moved it to a client test machine, which is a VM with Widnows Server 2008
I deployed it on the IIS there, and try it from the same machine.

The SaveFileDialog doesn't show up
I am accessing the VM through Citrix

any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

SaveFileDialog will throw a SecurityException if it is not user-initiated, such as by finishing a download. I'm not sure of the logic behind this, but check to make sure that SaveFileDialog is always shown directly from an EventHandler initiated by a user action.

Comment: Oh, and a download finishing actually wouldn't count. Just tested it. An acceptable event would be a button click. The reason why this works on your server is because its local, so the security settings are more lax.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you John. 
Actually it was Citrix problem , because the client can see the saveFileDialog, but I cannot see it.
But it is good idea to check what John mentioned about checking the security exception

Comment: Could you please formulate this as an answer to your question and mark it as answer? It would be nicer to read/more useful for people with the same issue. Thanks!